# cassandra benchmarking using thrift and CQL3

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cql3

I am doing performance testing of cassandra thrift vs CQL and I have used the following code to enter 1000 records in standard column family with  4 columns using CQL and thrift. But in contradiction to datastax I am getting higher throughput and less latency using thrift than using CQL. Can anyone help me if I am going wrong somewhere?

public void insertUsingCql() {

```
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Inserting using cql started at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            session.execute(boundStatement.bind(Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
        }

        System.out.println("Inserting using cql ended at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = end - start;
        System.out.println("Time taken is= " + diff);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

public void insertUsingThrift(String keyspace) {
        System.out.print(keyspace);

```
    try {
        Column col;
        ColumnOrSuperColumn column;

        client.set_keyspace(keyspace);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Inserting using thrift started at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                col = new Column();
                col.setName(ByteBuffer.wrap(Integer.toString(i).getBytes()));
                col.setValue(ByteBuffer.wrap(Integer.toString(i).getBytes()));
                col.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

                column = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
                column.setColumn(col);

                mutations.add(new Mutation().setColumn_or_supercolumn(column));
            }

            mutationMap.put("data", mutations);
            record.put(ByteBuffer.wrap(Integer.toString(j).getBytes()), mutationMap);
            client.batch_mutate(record, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
            mutations.clear();
            mutationMap.clear();
            record.clear();

        }

        System.out.println("Inserting using thrift ended at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = end - start;
        System.out.println("Time taken is= " + diff);
    } catch (InvalidRequestException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PerformaceTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnavailableException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PerformaceTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (TimedOutException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PerformaceTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (TException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PerformaceTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope you are not doing anything wrong, for this low volume thrift driver will look faster on average but it will have higher spikes on the 95th and 99th percentile, and it will get worst with increase in load. Try to use metrics for your performance testing http://metrics.codahale.com/ and look at the latency distribution rather than just mean response time.
Also be aware of cassandra caching, so that you do not run one test with cold cache and the next with warm cache.
From my experience use the native driver as it is widely supported and used where more likely the thrift driver will be dropped, specially with C* 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect performance increase if you replace `execute()` with `executeAsync()` and wait for all tasks to finish (Guava's `Futures.allAsList(...).get()` is a convenient way to do so).

It's not clear if you running it on local or distributed Cassandra installation. Performance gain should be higher in distributed environment, especially if you do some tuning upon `Cluster` initialization. But even on local Cassandra installation there must be visible improvement.

Also, I'd recommend to increase count of records in a loop to something like 1M and add warm-up cycles. It's possible that you've benchmarked not Cassandra, but JIT compiler in Cassandra JVM :)